# How to use two consecutive proxies?

Tags: proxy

I want to use two consecutive anonymous proxies. I mean, I have two anonymous proxies 
and I want to send my request from my computer through the first proxy to the second and then the second are going to send my request to the destination.

Is there any way to do this? What program should I use?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Only if:

- you control the first proxy, and can configure it to route requests to the second proxy
- or the first proxy accepts some special syntax to control routing the requests (eg, it could convert `http://realsite.com.proxy2.example.com/` into a request to `http://realsite.com/` routed via `proxy2.example.com`. I'm not aware of anything that does this out of the box.

[TOR](http://www.torproject.org/) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network))) does something similar to what you're after. Every packet that goes over TOR goes through ~3 intermediate hops. only the first intermediate hop knows where the traffic came from (but can't tell what was in the traffic; nor its ultimate destination). Only the last intermediate hop knows where the traffic is going (and what the unencrypted data is) - but it doesn't know where the data came from, nor does it know how to contact a machine that knows where the data came from.

This [isn't perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Weaknesses), but it's a good start towards anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a program you can use to do this.

The first proxy would need to be configured to allow this kind of proxy chaining. Are you able to configure it in this way?

Comment: no i can't configure the first proxy !