# connect two consecutive proxy servers

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, proxy

According to this question:

[How to use two consecutive proxies?](https://superuser.com/questions/91521/how-to-use-two-consecutive-proxies)

I can configure a proxy server(A) to route the requests into a second proxy server(B) only if proxy server(A) lets me to do this.

I have a Ccproxy installed on my Virtualbox guest OS. I want to connect this proxy server to another proxy server which is not under my control but I can use it as a client.

Does Ccproxy let me to connect it to the other proxy server? And If it doesn't, can I use the fact that my proxy server is on a virtual machine and configure something on my host OS (which is Ubuntu 14.04)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try instead [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com).  WinGate like CCProxy is a windows based proxy server. It is free for 10 concurrent users.  Its web proxy supports connecting via an upstream proxy (http, SOCKS4, SOCKS4A or HTTP tunneling).

[image]

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: link is there, also how it would help "supports connecting via an upstream proxy".  I'll add some images to make it more clear and bit more description about WinGate itself..